# How to run two describe blocks sequentially in a mocha-chai test suite

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

In one of my mocha-chai test, I have two describe blocks. In each describe block I have minimum two 'it' blocks. The second describe blocks repeats similar things what the first describe block does and something extra. When I am giving a run I feel that both the describe blocks start simultaneously one after another causing the test case fail. If I run them individually by commenting out one of the describe blocks they run fine.

Please notice that every time I am clearing the database and giving a run from the scratch so that each and every API that I test is self contained and not dependent on results of other describe blocks.

How can I sequence them so that the second describe blocks runs after the first and so on if I have more than two describe blocks.

Below is my code :

```
var server;
var mongodb;

before(function (done) {
    server = require('../../../app.js'); // same as "node app.js"
    done();
})

after(function (done) {
    server.close();
})

beforeEach(function (done){
    clear_the_db();
    done();
})

var json_obj = {"a":"b"};
function clear_the_db() {
    var mongoObj = mongoose.model('modelname');
    mongoObj.remove({}, function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log('MongoDb collections removed');
    } else {
        console.log('Error is= '+err);
    }
})

describe('First:POST call to insert data into project', ()=> {
    clear_the_db();
    it('First:Creating project', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
        .post('/create/myproject')
        .send()
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('First:Inserting data into created project', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
        .post('/data/myproject')
        .send(json_obj)
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

});
describe('Second:POST call to insert data into project', ()=> {
    clear_the_db();
    it('Second:Creating project', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
        .post('/create/myproject')
        .send()
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('Second:Inserting data into created project', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
        .post('/data/myproject')
        .send(json_obj)
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('Second:Fetching data from the created project', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/data/myproject')     
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Updated code after reading hooks from https://mochajs.org/:

```
var server;
var mongodb;

before(function (done) {
    server = require('../../../app.js'); // same as "node app.js"
    done();
})

after(function (done) {
    server.close();
})


var json_obj = {"a":"b"};
function clear_the_db() {
    var mongoObj = mongoose.model('modelname');
    mongoObj.remove({}, function(err){
        if(!err) {
            console.log('MongoDb collections removed');
        } else {
            console.log('Error is= '+err);
        }
    })
}

describe("This is outer-most describe", function() { 
    beforeEach(function (done){
        clear_the_db();
    })

    describe('First:POST call to insert data into project', ()=> {
        it('First:Creating project', (done) => {
            chai.request(server)
            .post('/create/myproject')
            .send()
            .end((err, res) => {
                 expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                 chai.request(server)
                .post('/data/myproject')
                .send(json_obj)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                });
                done();
            });
        });         
    });

    describe('Second:POST call to insert data into project', ()=> {
        it('Second:Creating project', (done) => {
            chai.request(server)
            .post('/create/myproject')
            .send()
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                chai.request(server)
                .post('/data/myproject')
                .send(json_obj)
                .end((err, res) => {
                     expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                     chai.request(server)
                     .get('/data/myproject')        
                     .end((err, res) => {
                         expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                     });
                });
                done();
            });
        });         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocha tests run sequantially by default. You must look for the problem elsewhere.

Possible reasons:

1. Both of your suites are with the same name -`POST call to insert data into project`.
2. If `clear_the_db();` is asynchronous, it is not guaranteed to have finished executing before running the `it()` blocks. Instead you should do the cleanup in a `beforeEach` hook callback and continue to the next test case when the task is finished. Example:

   ```
   function clear_the_db(doneCb) {
     var mongoObj = mongoose.model('modelname');

     mongoObj.remove({}, function(err){
       if(!err) {
         console.log('MongoDb collections removed');
       } else {
         console.log('Error is= '+err);
       }
       // call the Mocha done() callback function 
       doneCb();
     });
   }

   // in your beforeEach hook, pass 'done' to 'clear_the_db'
   beforeEach(function (done){
     clear_the_db(done);
   });
   ```

Comment: I have added the beforeEach block at the top and changed the test suite names by appening First: and Second: , but no help. Is the beforeEach block correctly added ? Thanks.

Comment: Is `clear_th_db` an async function? Does it accept a callback or does it return a `Promise`?

Comment: clear_the_db is an async function with callback, I have added it in my post. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check if it works for you now.

Comment: It seems like the beforeEach is getting executed before every it() block under the same describe(). Is it so ? I want the clear_the_db to be called once before each describe block.

Comment: Yes. It's counter-intuitive but it runs before each `it` block. See the issue here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/911. What I would do is to split the two 'describes' in two separate files.

Comment: I could make it work with the before and beforeEach block how you have shown. The problem was with the done statement in the it block, putting them in right place solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2017, I was having similar problems when I had multiple describes on the same js test file. On the same set of tests, they would sometime fail depending if I ran all the test under the project, ran all of the tests under debug, just that files test, or just one test. I tried various different methods of getting around this situation.  I was about to give up, but then decided to run it outside of Visual Studio and run it from the command line.  Voilà!!! It worked!!!

Comment: Roger I just posted two issues that sound exactly like the issue you are having.  Any time I have two describes in a test in Visual Studio they fail, whether at the root level or nested inside a higher level describe.  Did you ever find a way around this or is my only solution to go learn how to run the tests outside if Visual Studio? That would be new to me as I am brand new to unit testing node.js and have only tried running from within visual studio.

Comment: FYI my posts were:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290163/multiple-mocha-tests-fail-if-run-together-in-visual-studio
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353885/issue-running-node-js-unit-tests-in-visual-studio